# how can I hide the row of fixed data table with certain data from response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I have a nested data, parent rows and child rows in a fixed data table. What I want to do is to hide the child rows (identified by some property like non null parentId) initially. Parent row will have some link (show more) which when clicked will show the hidden children of the parent row. I am assuming the order of rows like:

```html
Parent 1 row 
child row1 of parent 1
child row2 of parent 1 
child row3 of parent 1 
...
child rown of parent 1
Parent 2 Row 
... 
...
Parent n Row
```

Has anyone tried nested fixed data table? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean it in html UI?

Comment: Yes @Kailas, inside UI.

Comment: Can you create a fddle for it please? So that we can understand the issue and your requirement better